# how change default telnet user&pass on wimax modem

Tags: wimax

As you know the default Telnet user&pass of bm632w Huawei series is wimax/wimax820

For security reason, we should change it
But there is no command for that!

Some guys suggest to open config file of the router and edit it but in bm632w it is encrypted file and we cannot open it with any editor ! :(
Another way I think is possible to open "/etc/defaultconfig.xml" and edit it....but my problem is I can't copy any file from modem to tftp (my computer)

If someone have known how to transfer file with tftp and cp (copy) command or have any new idea please share with us thanks!